# How to implement CN/DN certificate validation between two internal servers?

Tags: tls, authentication, openssl

In an internal environment I have two Windows servers which both have Internal CA Signed SSL Certificates used to implement a Mutual Authentication HTTPS connection. Is it mandated that a CN/DN Validation (DN check against a whitelist of clients) is put in place.

1. Are CN checks already in place for any HTTPS connection as per this [link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1)?

2. How would a DN check against a whitelist of clients be implemented in this particular situation?

For point 2 I would have thought some sort of application code to check the DN against a list of valid servers. Or could you put the connecting server public certificate in your own key store and whenever a connection is made only those servers with the public certificate in your own store can make a connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll not be able to provide an exact answer that will "solve" this problem since in the end it's kind of a broad question that can be tackled in different ways.

For all things related to TLS implementation the [OWASP Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet) is always a great reference and even starting point. It covers a lot of ground and can be useful throughout an implementation or application development.

Regarding your **first question**, [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125) specifies procedures for representing and verifying the identity of application services in such interactions.

Section 3.1 of [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) also describes how to correctly identify a Server.

I'm not quite sure what do you mean in the **second question**. If you're mentioning checks during the TLS handshake or if it's related to authentication. The handshake will only work if the client and server trust each other, therefore if there isn't a trust relationship between the peers the handshake will fail, this is already covered by TLS.